# Integrating over the ratio of a conditional pdf and a conditional cdf

Tags: integral

I have a question regarding an integration problem. Assume that we have 3 random variables $X$,$Y$,$Z$ where $Z$ is a binary variable and we want to calculate

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f_{Y|X}(y|x)}{f_{Z|XY}(1|x,y)}dy$.

We know that we can write $f_{Z|XY}(1|x,y)$ as

$f_{Z|XY}(1|x,y)=\Phi(\theta_{1}y+\theta_{2}x)$

(where $\Phi(\cdot)$ gives the standard normal cdf) and that $Y|X$ is conditional normal, that is

$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp[-0.5(y-x\beta)^2]$.

Hence the problem becomes the question of how to solve

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-0.5[y-x\beta)^2]}{\Phi(\theta_{1}y+\theta_{2}x)}dy$.

I would be happy if anyone could give some advice.

Comment: Presumably $|\theta_1|\lt 1$.  Consider approximations or numerical solutions--a closed form looks unlikely except possibly for very special values of $\theta_1$.

Comment: Yeah I already though about numerical solutions or approximations but I thought maybe there is a special trick or something that works because everything is normal. Thank you